# Unknown manufacturer of services in windows system configuration

Tags: malware, windows-10, service-tag

I would like to ask if I can trust unknown manufacturer detected by windows system configuration.

As you can see in the screenshot, all of the other services is known manufacturer but there is one service that using asus name but their manufacturer is unknown.

And after that how do I analysis it to check if it is really a malware ?
doing static analysis ? dynamic analysis ?

[image]

Comment: Most likely just a process problem as ASUS but it's impossible to tell from the information. I would first open services.msc, check the "Path to executable" for the service of that name and send the file/hash to VirusTotal as a double check.  Process Explorer can automate this process if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That service is created by the ASUS PTP driver, which for Intel 7th and 8th CPU units/devices, is the official replacement of the "Smart Gesture" touch-pad driver.

For the new systems, it comes pre-installed and is update-able to the latest driver version by running the standard Windows Update.

The manufacturer tag will probably get and update and show correctly in future versions.

So if you use a 7th or 8th gen CPU it should be entirely legit. There's also no reason for a malware to name itself like that, as it would have a very limited coverage; a malware will most likely use a more universal name. Nothing prevents you though from running some anti-malware scans on your system.